# Reading Windows credentials

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-7, windows-authentication

Have just deployed an ASP.NET app (VB) to a local IIS server (the same machine the code was developed on) and I'm having trouble reading the Windows authentication details.

When running purely in debug mode I can read them fine using `Me.Context.User.Identity.Name`, `Request.ServerVariables("Auth_User")` or `Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name`, but when this runs in IIS - even if I attach Visual Studio to it and run in debug mode, the first two give blank results and the third gives `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR` (the anonymous user identity).

Just to stress, I don't want IIS to authenticate these details automatically, I just need to be able to read them in the code.

I have tried enabling and disabling Anonymous authentication and Windows authentication in IIS but no change.

Can anyone suggest what else I should check?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you enabled "ASP .NET Impersonation" in IIS?

Comment: No I haven't done this.

Comment: Try it.  And disable "Anonymous Authentication"

Comment: Firstly I want anonymous access as well, but I want to be able to tell the difference between internal and external users. Secondly, is impersonation necessary if I want to read the current user's credentials??

Comment: Forgot to say, I tried disabling anonymous authentication but no difference.

Comment: What user is IIS running as?  That's probably your issue.

Comment: Do you mean the Anonymous User Identity? That is IUSR

Comment: No, I mean what user is the IIS Application Pool using.

Comment: That is ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: Try changing it to NetworkService

Comment: Good suggestion but no difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you have to disable anonymous authentication to get the identity informations.

Comment: I think you are right. Is there a way to allow both anonymous as well as users with credentials?

Comment: you could setup 2 IIS Sites with diffrent URL (Host's  e.g. internal.mysite.com and www.mysite.com) and diffrent authentification settings.